# C# CLR, not able to connect to excel file

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, clr, oledbconnection

I'm trying to connect to an xlsx file from a CLR procedure. 
I ran the code in a simple tester (not clr, just a console app) and it works.
but when I try to run (the same code), in SQL serve management 2008 , I get the error: "Unspecified error".

here is the c# code:

```
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void GetURLandQueueByCLID(SqlString phoneNumber, SqlString isDebug, string wsURL, out SqlInt32 queue, out SqlInt32 priority, out SqlString attData)
{
 string[] parameters = new string[3] { "", "", "" };
        try
        {
            DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();

            string filePath = @"C:\Excel_route_file\ms.xlsx";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"))
            {
                Helper.WriteLogToDB("before open");
                conn.Open();

                OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] where '0575271470' = phone", conn);

                Helper.WriteLogToDB("before fill");
                sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);

                parameters[0] = sheetData.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                parameters[1] = sheetData.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                parameters[2] = sheetData.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();

                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helper.WriteLogToDB("fail to fill: " + ex.Message);
        }


        queue = SqlInt32.Parse(parameters [0]);
        priority = SqlInt32.Parse(parameters [1]);
        attData = parameters [2];
 }
```

it doesn't reaches the conn.Open()  :(
it's something in the OleDbConnection creation.

the creat procedure:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proName]
  (@PHONENUMBER [nvarchar](MAX),@ISDEBUG [nvarchar](MAX),@WSURL [nvarchar] (MAX),@QUEUE INT OUTPUT ,@PRIORITY INT OUTPUT,@ATTDATA [nvarchar](MAX) OUTPUT)

  WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS

  EXTERNAL NAME [assemblyName].[StoredProcedures].[GetURLandQueueByCLID]
  GO
```

the ASSEMBLY is created with PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

I also did this:

```
 ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

and this:

```
 sp_configure 'clr enabled',1
 GO
 RECONFIGURE
 GO
 sp_configure 'clr enabled'  -- make sure it took
 GO
```

I can't make it to work, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, problem in the OleDbConnection creation. Add quotes around the value of  Extended Properties.

```
new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';")
```